# Everything will not just turn into vapor in the ground zero of nuclear explosions but hydrogen plasma

Tags: nuclear-physics, temperature, plasma-physics, explosions, elements

Calcium atoms can't withstand extreme heat according to this link. http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast122/lectures/lec09.html "Why do some stars have strong lines of hydrogen, others strong lines of calcium? The answer was not composition (all stars are 95% hydrogen) but rather surface temperature.

As temperature increases, electrons are kicked up to higher levels (remember the Bohr model) by collisions with other atoms. Large atoms have more kinetic energy, and their electrons are excited first, followed by lower mass atoms.

If the collision is strong enough (high temperatures) then the electron is knocked off the atom and we say the atom is ionized. So as we go from low temperatures in stars (couple 1,000K) we see heavy atoms, like calcium and magnesium, in the stars spectrum. As the temperature increases, we see lighter atoms, such as hydrogen (the heavier atoms are all ionized by this point and have no electrons to produce absorption lines)."

So, everything including heavier elements such as calcium will be reduced to helium and hydrogen in the ground zero of nuclear explosions because the temperature at ground zero reach millions of degree Celsius. Correct?

Comment: *all stars are 95% hydrogen* what? where did that fake statistic come from?

Comment: @KyleKanos Not sure, that's what was said in the link.

Comment: Well that's clearly not at all true. Neutron stars, for instance, are *not* made of hydrogen.

Comment: @KyleKanos during the supernovae explosion, only nuclei in the core of the supernovae get destroyed while nuclei on the surface get ejected, correct?

Comment: how are you defining "destroyed"? And which class of SNe are you considering I(a|b|c)? II? PISNe? Other?

Comment: @KyleKanos what I mean by destruction is totally change the structure of the nuclei into something really different. For example, lighter nuclei such as phosphorus breaking into several different parts that are no longer phosphorus. PM2Ring have answered that in the core of star where fusion is no longer working, nuclei will disintegrated but we are talking about stars that still don't explode.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what "totally change the structure of the nuclei" means, but it sounds like you're describing [photo-disintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodisintegration)? If so, then yes, that can happen in the core of a star that is exploding (though technically that is the *cause* of the explosion and so must happen *before* it).

Comment: @KyleKanos yes that's it. Photodisintegration and transmutation are basically the same processes. But how about the process when the scientists at CERN generated heat at 5.5 trillion degrees Celsius where nuclei started to melt into quarks and gluons? Is that transmutation too or some kind of other process?

Answer (score 2):

The temperature of a nuclear explosion won’t cause the nuclei of calcium atoms to come apart into helium and hydrogen nuclei.  That process needs even more extreme conditions, because the transition the other way (toward heavier nuclei) is energetically preferred: fusion liberates energy by colliding lighter nuclei and turning them into heavier ones.

What the high temperature will do is excite and largely strip the electrons from those nuclei.  That’s what’s causing the behavior of the spectral lines.

Comment: Gotcha. So maybe by bombarding calcium with alpha particles so the protons of the calcium or basically nuclei will get scattered and shattered? This is one of the answer I got when I asked how to change calcium atoms into wholly different entities. What are other processes that can turn calcium atoms into different elements, others, etc.?

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah A lot of energy is involved and the only way is scattering with high energy particles in accelerators, and the reslult is probabilistic.

Comment: @anna v Probabilistic? This article said they successfully break calcium and neon https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.51.8

Comment: @Bob Jacobsen so even in the star's core which temperature is millions of degree, there are calcium nuclei?

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @BobJacobsen what about in the star's core where temperature is millions of degrees? Can calcium nuclei survived there for too long?

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah by probabilistic I mean follow quantum mechanical scatteriing equations.

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah A few million degrees encourages fusion of light nuclei, but when the temperature gets into the billions the ambient photons are gamma rays with enough energy to knock protons & alpha particles out of nuclei. This process is called photodisintegration, and becomes important in the last week or so of the life of large stars. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon-burning_process

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for your answer. If calcium nuclei can withstand the heat of star's core which is at millions of degrees and not to mention that star core is the place where fusion takes place, I think there will be no calcium nuclei in quasars because quasars are much hotter at trillions of degrees. Thoughts?

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah A quasar is a type of [Active Galactic Nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_galactic_nucleus). They are large structures, and the temperature varies over the structure. Certainly, the hottest parts are hot enough for photodisintegration, but the spectra of AGN show emission lines from a variety of light elements, upto iron. However, comments aren't a good place for discussion, chat is much better for that.

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah The key point of Bob's answer is that you're misinterpreting the quoted material in your question. When they say *(the heavier atoms are all ionized by this point and have no electrons to produce absorption lines)* that means those atoms are totally ionized, they have no electrons left, so they can't produce emission or absorption lines. However, at those temperatures, the *nuclei* of the atoms are still intact, so a calcium nucleus still has its usual number of protons and neutrons.

Comment: @PM2Ring I see. How do I discuss this with you through chat? I'm using a phone right now.